# pip install in developper shell for VC2019 yields "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required." error

Tags: python, windows, pip

I have installed vc2019 as needed and tried to run `pip install` in the VC2019 developer shell on a package that needs compilation. Normally all required environment variables should be set. I just changed the cwd to my package to install.

However, I still get the error "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required". I thus can't compile the package.

`setuptools` is up to date (v53.0.0) and `pip` is up to date also (v21.0.0). I'm using python 3.8.

Why can't it find the vc compilation tool ?

The code to compile is a simple c library, not c++.

Comment: You could try and debug this using procmon or similar to see what registry keys it's using to try and find Visual Studio and what file paths it's checking, but that's going to be a lot of sifting though noise.

Comment: Can you find a pre-built package e.g. from Anaconda? That's generally easier than fighting pip.

Comment: @Rup unfortunately, I'm a linux user that tries to make a python package that can be used on Windows. So I don't know much windows and couldn't follow your suggestion. It seam that I should better make a precompiled package (wheel) for Windows. I must now find out how to do this.

Comment: @Rup it's my own package with my own code that I want to install on Windows.

Comment: Ah, fair enough! (I nearly suggested use WSL or a Linux VM instead :-) ) [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) is a SysInternals tools that is essentially 'strace everything', and you can filter the output but it's still generally time consuming to find what you're looking for. A better idea would be to try and find more verbose output modes for pip so hopefully it'll show you what it's doing instead.